# How to filter a dataframe of dates and hours by a list of dates?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filter, datetimeindex

I have the following dataframe, with several days and a measure every 15minutes:

```
                 CONSUMPTION
2016-11-01 01:00:00  3539
2016-11-01 01:15:00  3560
2016-11-01 01:30:00  3505
....
2016-11-02 01:00:00  3400
2016-11-02 01:15:00  3447
....
2016-11-03 01:00:00  2400
2016-11-03 01:15:00  2447
```

Every works if ask for a simple day:

```
df['2016-11-01']
```

and I get all the measure for that day, 96 measures:

```
    CONSUMPTION
2016-11-01 01:00:00  3539
2016-11-01 01:15:00  3560
2016-11-01 01:30:00  3505
....
```

But **my problem** is that I want to get a list of dates, and this doesn't work:

```
df[['2016-11-01','2016-11-03']]
```

The most I have achieved is this (but this is not what I want, observed that 1 get a measure per day, instead my 96 expected measures):

```
qwe=['2016-11-01','2016-11-03']
df.ix[df.index.to_datetime().isin(qwe)]

            CONSUMPTION
2016-11-01  3539
2016-11-03  2400
```

Any idea would be appreciated.....

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Floor the datetime to Day and then use isin and loc i.e

```
li = ['2016-11-01','2016-11-02']
df.loc[(df.index.floor('D').isin(li)),:]

                    CONSUMPTION
Date                            
2016-11-01 01:00:00         3539
2016-11-01 01:15:00         3560
2016-11-01 01:30:00         3505
2016-11-02 01:00:00         3400
2016-11-02 01:15:00         3447
```

Comment: Izaskun you can vote the answer too if it was helpful

Comment: after tinkering 1h with index.date... MWAH!

Comment: Took too long to find this...  would be much more intuitive if we could use a list of strings for this just as a single string. In half a year I'm going to search for this again...

Answer (score 0):

This works for hours :

```
hours = [0, 6, 12, 18]
df.loc[(df.index.hour.isin(hours)),:]
```